# Overwrite request object in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have `base` class for every request in my app:

```
public abstract class BaseDto
{
   public string Uid { get; set; }
}

public class RequestDto : BaseDto
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Im using my `ReuqestDto` class in my controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get(RequestDto req)
{
    // some logic on request
    if (req.Uid != null)
    {
        // perform action
    }

}
```

The user passing only `SomeData` property to me. In my JWT Token i have saved some information about `Uid` for `BaseDto`. What is the best way to write data to `Uid` using middleware/filter to have that information in my `Get()` method? I Tried to serialized `HttpContext.Request.Body` but not success because i cant find, how to do it properly. Or maybe there are better solutions for this problem? How to write data to my incoming objects in app?

Comment: Model binding attribute could help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Comment: That or using a request filter. doing it in a middleware might be too early in the flow.

Comment: Thanks for advice, could you provide your comment with answer, how to overwrite request object in .net core? Can be filter. I'm just wondering is it possible in webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want.

You should to create own interface for models like that

```
public interface IMyRequestType { }
```

Your model should implement it for finding model in FilterAttribute

```
public class MyModel : IMyRequestType
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

And create your filter attribute with `OnActionExecuting` implentation

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyFilterAttribute() : base(typeof(MyFilterImpl)) { }

    private class MyFilterImpl : IActionFilter
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public MyFilterAttributeImpl(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            // get something from DI
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyFilterAttributeImpl>();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            // get your request model
            var model = context.ActionArguments.Values.OfType<IMyRequestType>().Single();

            // get your key
            //context.HttpContext.User or whatever

            // do something with model
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // perform some logic work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I often created a filter which implements [Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute) and [IAsyncActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iasyncactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get the information before go inside the Controller's action.

Here is an example,

```cs
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

 public class UserProfileFilter : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
 {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            string uid = string.Empty;
            StringValues authHeaderVal = default(StringValues);

            // Get UID from JWT
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out authHeaderVal))
            {
                string bearerTokenPrefix = "Bearer";
                string accessToken = string.Empty;
                string authHeaderStr = authHeaderVal.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authHeaderStr) && authHeaderStr.StartsWith(bearerTokenPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    accessToken = authHeaderStr.Replace(bearerTokenPrefix, string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Trim();
                }

                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken);
                uid = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("sub", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
            }

            // Or Get UID from ActionExecutingContext
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                uid = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.Equals("sub", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))?.Value;
            }

            // Get payload
            RequestDto payload = (RequestDto)context.ActionArguments?.Values.FirstOrDefault(v => v is RequestDto);
            payload.Uid = uid;

            await next();
        }
}
```

And then you can put the filter on any action.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[TypeFilter(typeof(UserProfileFilter))]
public ActionResult<IActionResult> AdminGet(RequestDto request)
{           
   Debug.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request));
   return this.Ok();
}
```

The above filter will use the `sub` claim's value to overwrite the value of the incoming payload.

For example, if I post the payload as following,

```json
{
    "uid" : "",
    "someData": "Test"
}
```

The action will finally output `{"Uid":"MyID","SomeData":"Test"}`.